# Create a dynamic database with sqlite

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I need a class to add tables at my sqlite database on the run, but I don't how to do it, I'm new to android programming.
  Also tutorial's links or any suggestions would be useful to me.

Comment: Do you meant that you want to add sqlite table on runtime? 
Why do you need that? Usually, a database should be designed previously.

Comment: Yes i need exactly this... Because i need to create an item in a list that opens an other list.

Comment: If you have other idias you're welcome